# Using functions in Blazegraph

Tags: blazegraph

I see some functions documented in Blazegraph, for instance in cern.jet.math.Function: https://blazegraph.github.io/database/apidocs/index.html?cern/jet/math/package-summary.html

I am wondering whether it is possible to use these functions in a Blazegraph's SPARQL endpoint? The only documented use I can find is for the GAS queries: `SERVICE gas:service { gas:program gas:gasClass "com.bigdata.rdf.graph.analytics.BFS" ...`

Answer (score 1):

These seem to be there as part of colt package, but not connected to actual SPARQL functions. You could define custom functions though as described in https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/CustomFunction - this way you could implement any math function.